# The differences between C++03 and C++14

Tags: c++

I'm Learning C++ and have taken a book, released in 2005, out from a library that teaches C++ using C++03.

Is the knowledge in this book still relevant at an intermediate level? Or should I get a more up to date book? If not, what parts that conflict with C++14 should I avoid?

Answer (score 1):

The book still has value, as the core of the language is quite stable.

That said, if you are going to go to the trouble of working through a book, you should find a good book. And I would also find a newer book that will cover the latest changes.

Comment: For a good list of books. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 0):

First learn the fundamentals, then you can look at the difference between the newer standards. For that a page like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) can help.

Personally I think C++11 and C++14 introduced more advanced features than fundamental features.

For example, you first need to understand a normal `for` loop before you should try to understand the `ranged-based for` that came with C++11.

With that view, C++03 is a good starting point.